# To show the following condition satisfied by a complex number.

Tags: complex-analysis

I am asked to show that 
$|\Re(2 + \bar{z} + z^3)|$ is less than or equal to $4$ when $|z|$ is less than or equal to $1$.

I tried to solve it by substituting complex number $z$ by $x+iy$ , its conjugate by $x-iy$ and the cubic expansion.
Then I found its real part i.e 
4(2+ x + x^3 - 3 x y^2)$.

Now as my aim is to take modulus of this real part,
and I have to use the fact that modulus of $z$ is less than or equal to $1$; how can I proceed?.

It would be of great help if someone suggest me the easy way to show this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Kavita, you have asked enough questions to know about MathJax and its usage on this site. Please **use it** in the future.

Comment: Sure Silvia, I will try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using $\Re(z)\leq |z|$ and triangle inequality, we have

$\left|\Re(2+\overline{z}+z^3)\right|\leq \left| 2+\overline{z}+z^3\right|\leq  2+|\overline{z}|+|z|^3\leq 2+1+1=4 $

Comment: The proof is too simple and proper. Thanks a lot User Suhail

Answer (score 1):

This is easier than you might think. We have:
$$
|2+\bar z +z^3|\leq |2|+|\bar z|+|z^3|\\
\leq 2+1+1=4
$$
Since the absolute value of the number itself is less than our equal to $4$, the real part must necessarily be less than or equal to $4$ as well.